# Appcelerator : I'm failing at 403 during build

Tags: titanium, titanium-sdk

```
$ appc ti build -T dist-adhoc

Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 7.1.2
Copyright (c) 2014-2020, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

An uncaught exception was thrown!
Rebuild failed:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.10.3
node-pre-gyp info using node@13.11.0 | darwin | x64
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/test/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/8.1.1.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v79-darwin-x64/node_ios_device.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v1.6.3/node_ios_device-v1.6.3-node-v79-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 403 https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v1.6.3/node_ios_device-v1.6.3-node-v79-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v1.6.3/node_ios_device-v1.6.3-node-v79-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for node-ios-device@1.6.3 and node@13.11.0 (node-v79 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v1.6.3/node_ios_device-v1.6.3-node-v79-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'node-gyp clean' (Error: spawn node-gyp ENOENT)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/test/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/8.1.1.GA/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:77:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.3.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.11.0/bin/node" "/Users/test/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/8.1.1.GA/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/test/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/8.1.1.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v13.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

No matter which version of the SDK you choose, access will be denied.

Is this not possible to build until the other server grants access?

Comment: see if this can help you. https://github.com/appcelerator/ioslib/issues/114

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please downgrade your Node version to 12.x (LTS version). Also I would suggest updating the SDK to a newer release: if you have to stay with 8 the you can use 8.3.1.GA; 9.0.1.GA would be even better of course. That might already fix the issue.

Comment: Yes. this works for me also. Downgrading node will work.

Comment: https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v1.7.0/node_ios_device-v1.7.0-node-v79-darwin-x64.tar.gz.

Version is now 9.0.1.GA. It is still rejected at 403.

Comment: can you try to install it by hand with `npm i -g node-ios-device@1.7.0`

Comment: node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v1.7.0/node_ios_device-v1.7.0-node-v79-darwin-x64.tar.gz

Comment: interesting, for me it will download this version:  https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v1.7.0/node_ios_device-v1.7.0-node-v64-darwin-x64.tar.gz (v64 instead of v79) - did you downgrade node?

Comment: I changed to v12.17.0 and it's fixed. Thank you.

Comment: I also needed to build against the git version not the zip download that is provided..

Answer (score 0):

Had a right headache sorting this out.

Run

```
appc ti info
```

And you might get this error.

```
ERROR: appc requires Node.js >=10.13.0
Visit http://nodejs.org/ to download a newer version.
```

Go to this link. https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

And download the .pkg for your specific node release do not install the latest as it crashes with the gyp errors.

After installing the latest package run.

```
node -v
```

Then

```
appc ti info
```

And hopefully, that works for you.